# Plotting a smooth line through a set of geospatial points

Tags: r, points-to-line, multipoint

I have a number of (long, lat) points as plotted below:

```
ggplot(data=transect,aes(x=long,y=lat)) + 
  geom_point( )
```

[image]
I have posted the raw data below. I would like to fit a smooth spatial line through these points, in `r`. I thought there would be a nice `r` function, but I cannot seem to find anything that plots a smooth curve.

Data below:

```
structure(list(lat = c(-1.384, -1.38, -1.38, -1.375, -1.375, 
-1.375, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.382, -1.377, -1.376, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.382, -1.382, -1.381, -1.384, 
-1.384, -1.381, -1.381, -1.381, -1.381, -1.38, -1.38, -1.379, 
-1.379, -1.378, -1.378, -1.375, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, 
-1.381, -1.379, -1.379, -1.378, -1.375, -1.376, -1.384, -1.384, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.383, 
-1.383, -1.382, -1.382, -1.381, -1.38, -1.379, -1.379, -1.378, 
-1.378, -1.377, -1.375, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.377, 
-1.376, -1.376, -1.376, -1.375, -1.38, -1.38, -1.38, -1.38, -1.378, 
-1.378, -1.377, -1.383, -1.384, -1.385, -1.385, -1.386, -1.384, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.383, -1.383, -1.384, -1.382, 
-1.382, -1.381, -1.381, -1.381, -1.381, -1.381, -1.379, -1.379, 
-1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.377, -1.377, -1.377, -1.377, 
-1.376, -1.376, -1.375, -1.375, -1.375, -1.374, -1.375, -1.374, 
-1.374, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.382, -1.382, -1.382, 
-1.381, -1.379, -1.378, -1.377, -1.377, -1.377, -1.375, -1.375, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.383, -1.381, -1.382, -1.38, 
-1.379, -1.379, -1.377, -1.376, -1.375, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.383, 
-1.383, -1.383, -1.383, -1.382, -1.377, -1.377, -1.377, -1.377, 
-1.377, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.383, -1.382, -1.382, 
-1.382, -1.381, -1.381, -1.381, -1.38, -1.379, -1.377, -1.375, 
-1.38388, -1.38384, -1.38386, -1.38386, -1.38365, -1.38393, -1.38393, 
-1.38366, -1.38368, -1.38358, -1.38358, -1.38358, -1.38358, -1.38313, 
-1.38307, -1.38251, -1.38267, -1.3824, -1.38148, -1.38156, -1.37967, 
-1.37968, -1.37926, -1.37857, -1.37772, -1.37699, -1.37662, -1.37615, 
-1.37521, -1.37525, -1.38383, -1.38383, -1.38383, -1.38383, -1.38383, 
-1.38383, -1.38397, -1.38382, -1.38365, -1.38364, -1.38353, -1.38352, 
-1.38356, -1.38356, -1.38356, -1.3826, -1.38171, -1.38008, -1.3801, 
-1.3801, -1.38008, -1.3801, -1.37797, -1.37797, -1.37797, -1.37473, 
-1.37472, -1.38394, -1.38394, -1.38394, -1.38394, -1.38394, -1.38394, 
-1.38406, -1.38406, -1.38397, -1.38397, -1.38397, -1.38397, -1.3838, 
-1.3838, -1.3838, -1.3838, -1.3838, -1.38386, -1.38384, -1.38372, 
-1.38351, -1.38111, -1.38116, -1.37887, -1.37883, -1.37883, -1.37883, 
-1.37883, -1.37528, -1.37528, -1.37528, -1.37473, -1.384, -1.384, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, 
-1.383, -1.383, -1.381, -1.381, -1.381, -1.38, -1.38, -1.38, 
-1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.376, -1.376, 
-1.376, -1.376, -1.375, -1.375, -1.38357, -1.38347, -1.38303, 
-1.38269, -1.38202, -1.38021, -1.3802, -1.37804, -1.37761, -1.37762, 
-1.37696, -1.37517, -1.37517, -1.37517, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, 
-1.384, -1.383, -1.383, -1.384, -1.384, -1.383, -1.383, -1.383, 
-1.383, -1.382, -1.382, -1.382, -1.382, -1.38, -1.38, -1.38, 
-1.38, -1.38, -1.379, -1.379, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, 
-1.378, -1.377, -1.377, -1.377, -1.376, -1.376, -1.376, -1.375, 
-1.375, -1.375, -1.375, -1.375, -1.3838, -1.3838, -1.38396, -1.38396, 
-1.38396, -1.38396, -1.38393, -1.38378, -1.38378, -1.38348, -1.38349, 
-1.38346, -1.3835, -1.3835, -1.3835, -1.3838, -1.38377, -1.384, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.383, -1.383, 
-1.383, -1.383, -1.383, -1.384, -1.383, -1.383, -1.383, -1.383, 
-1.382, -1.382, -1.382, -1.382, -1.382, -1.382, -1.381, -1.38, 
-1.38, -1.38, -1.38, -1.38, -1.38, -1.379, -1.379, -1.378, -1.377, 
-1.377, -1.377, -1.377, -1.375, -1.375, -1.375, -1.375, -1.384, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.383, -1.383, -1.381, 
-1.38, -1.378, -1.377, -1.377, -1.375, -1.375, -1.375, -1.384, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.383, -1.383, -1.383, 
-1.381, -1.381, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.375, -1.375, -1.375, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.384, -1.383, -1.383, -1.383, -1.383, 
-1.383, -1.382, -1.382, -1.382, -1.382, -1.381, -1.38, -1.38, 
-1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, -1.378, 
-1.378, -1.377, -1.377, -1.377, -1.377, -1.375, -1.375, -1.375, 
-1.375, -1.375, -1.38385, -1.38381, -1.38167, -1.3816, -1.3814, 
-1.37957, -1.37777, -1.37522, -1.37523, -1.37523, -1.3747, -1.38398, 
-1.38378, -1.3836, -1.38361, -1.37953, -1.37716, -1.3771, -1.37477, 
-1.37473, -1.37476, -1.38647, -1.38402, -1.38395, -1.38381, -1.38358, 
-1.38358, -1.38358, -1.38357, -1.3834, -1.38333, -1.38296, -1.38295, 
-1.38296, -1.38296, -1.3817, -1.38171, -1.3817, -1.38168, -1.3817, 
-1.38063, -1.38064, -1.38065, -1.37999, -1.38, -1.38, -1.37999, 
-1.38001, -1.38, -1.37872, -1.37872, -1.37769, -1.37772, -1.37703, 
-1.37702, -1.37702, -1.37666, -1.37664, -1.37607, -1.37607, -1.37609, 
-1.37544, -1.37543, -1.37544, -1.37544, -1.37546, -1.37476, -1.37477, 
-1.38381, -1.38384, -1.38382, -1.38382, -1.38381, -1.38386, -1.38397, 
-1.38377, -1.3838, -1.38381, -1.38377, -1.38378, -1.38354, -1.38357, 
-1.38356, -1.38356, -1.38355, -1.38334, -1.38331, -1.38304, -1.38306, 
-1.38306, -1.38258, -1.38259, -1.38259, -1.38258, -1.38258, -1.3826, 
-1.38214, -1.38214, -1.38214, -1.38073, -1.38002, -1.38001, -1.38001, 
-1.38002, -1.37938, -1.37767, -1.37766, -1.37766, -1.37689, -1.37686, 
-1.37552, -1.37553, -1.38551, -1.38381, -1.38395, -1.38394, -1.38392, 
-1.38377, -1.38364, -1.38356, -1.38356, -1.38356, -1.38354, -1.38355, 
-1.38302, -1.38291, -1.3829, -1.38274, -1.38259, -1.38258, -1.38176, 
-1.38169, -1.38135, -1.3814, -1.38, -1.38, -1.37898, -1.37896, 
-1.37842, -1.37664, -1.37636, -1.37579, -1.37514, -1.37516, -1.37513, 
-1.3838, -1.38402, -1.384, -1.38395, -1.38397, -1.38396, -1.3838, 
-1.3838, -1.38378, -1.38354, -1.37868, -1.37875, -1.37872, -1.37874, 
-1.37666, -1.37668, -1.37532, -1.3753, -1.37531, -1.37535, -1.37454, 
-1.384, -1.384, -1.383, -1.38388, -1.38385, -1.38404, -1.38396, 
-1.38396, -1.38396, -1.38396, -1.38369, -1.38378, -1.38378, -1.38356, 
-1.38363, -1.38363, -1.38363, -1.38359, -1.38235, -1.38029, -1.37945, 
-1.37942, -1.37864, -1.37822, -1.37721, -1.37677, -1.37475, -1.37478, 
-1.37478, -1.38379, -1.38379, -1.3838, -1.38379, -1.38378, -1.38369, 
-1.38368, -1.38358, -1.38358, -1.38358, -1.38344, -1.38303, -1.38305, 
-1.38263, -1.38262, -1.38262, -1.38238, -1.38237, -1.38238, -1.38182, 
-1.38097, -1.38014, -1.38014, -1.38014, -1.37996, -1.37868, -1.3787, 
-1.37869, -1.37736, -1.37701, -1.38378, -1.3838, -1.38385, -1.38385, 
-1.38388, -1.37553, -1.37518, -1.3838, -1.38391, -1.3839, -1.38393, 
-1.38413, -1.38396, -1.38408, -1.38408, -1.38403, -1.38403, -1.38403, 
-1.38403, -1.38376, -1.38356, -1.38363, -1.38349, -1.38363, -1.38373, 
-1.38345, -1.38322, -1.38192, -1.38177, -1.38039, -1.37928, -1.37909, 
-1.3784, -1.37811, -1.37793, -1.37793, -1.37793, -1.37724, -1.37536, 
-1.37522, -1.37522, -1.38382, -1.38379, -1.38383, -1.38383, -1.38381, 
-1.38381, -1.38382, -1.38383, -1.38381, -1.38381, -1.38382, -1.3838, 
-1.3838, -1.38381, -1.38379, -1.38381, -1.38379, -1.38379, -1.38379, 
-1.38379, -1.38378, -1.38354, -1.38355, -1.38356, -1.38358, -1.38356, 
-1.38308, -1.38306, -1.38312, -1.38252, -1.38248, -1.38248, -1.38249, 
-1.38251, -1.3825, -1.3825, -1.38052, -1.38054, -1.37957, -1.37957, 
-1.37856, -1.3785, -1.37854, -1.37857, -1.37856, -1.37818, -1.37816, 
-1.37816, -1.377, -1.37698, -1.377, -1.37695, -1.37701, -1.37697, 
-1.37698, -1.3752, -1.37524, -1.37522, -1.37522, -1.37522, -1.37521, 
-1.3752), long = c(35.387, 35.393, 35.393, 35.388, 35.388, 35.387, 
35.387, 35.387, 35.39, 35.391, 35.393, 35.39, 35.389, 35.387, 
35.39, 35.391, 35.391, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.387, 35.388, 
35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.392, 35.392, 
35.392, 35.392, 35.389, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 35.393, 
35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 
35.387, 35.389, 35.389, 35.389, 35.389, 35.39, 35.391, 35.393, 
35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 
35.391, 35.388, 35.387, 35.387, 35.388, 35.388, 35.39, 35.39, 
35.389, 35.389, 35.388, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.392, 
35.392, 35.391, 35.39, 35.388, 35.387, 35.388, 35.388, 35.388, 
35.388, 35.388, 35.388, 35.389, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.393, 
35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.392, 35.392, 
35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 
35.389, 35.389, 35.389, 35.389, 35.387, 35.388, 35.389, 35.388, 
35.387, 35.387, 35.389, 35.391, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 
35.393, 35.392, 35.391, 35.39, 35.39, 35.389, 35.388, 35.387, 
35.387, 35.387, 35.39, 35.392, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.392, 
35.392, 35.391, 35.389, 35.387, 35.387, 35.388, 35.388, 35.388, 
35.388, 35.388, 35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 35.392, 35.392, 35.393, 
35.393, 35.393, 35.391, 35.391, 35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 35.388, 
35.389, 35.388, 35.392, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 
35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.39, 35.388, 35.38702, 35.38703, 
35.38688, 35.38688, 35.38903, 35.38926, 35.38956, 35.39033, 35.39031, 
35.39082, 35.39082, 35.39082, 35.39082, 35.39235, 35.39238, 35.39285, 
35.39295, 35.39298, 35.39317, 35.39319, 35.39289, 35.39289, 35.39275, 
35.39245, 35.39189, 35.39077, 35.39047, 35.38973, 35.38855, 35.38849, 
35.38687, 35.38687, 35.38687, 35.38687, 35.38687, 35.38687, 35.38835, 
35.38943, 35.39001, 35.39002, 35.39031, 35.39096, 35.39095, 35.39095, 
35.39095, 35.39284, 35.39316, 35.39305, 35.39306, 35.39303, 35.39303, 
35.39306, 35.39192, 35.39192, 35.39192, 35.38738, 35.38739, 35.38683, 
35.38683, 35.38683, 35.38683, 35.38683, 35.38683, 35.38817, 35.38817, 
35.3882, 35.3882, 35.3882, 35.3882, 35.3895, 35.3895, 35.3895, 
35.3895, 35.3895, 35.38968, 35.39004, 35.39086, 35.39101, 35.39317, 
35.39315, 35.39234, 35.39243, 35.39243, 35.39243, 35.39243, 35.38853, 
35.38853, 35.38853, 35.38735, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 
35.388, 35.388, 35.388, 35.388, 35.389, 35.391, 35.392, 35.392, 
35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.392, 35.392, 
35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.39, 35.39, 35.389, 35.389, 
35.387, 35.387, 35.39012, 35.39166, 35.39237, 35.39279, 35.39318, 
35.39308, 35.39308, 35.39193, 35.39162, 35.39166, 35.39083, 35.38847, 
35.38847, 35.38847, 35.387, 35.387, 35.388, 35.388, 35.39, 35.39, 
35.392, 35.392, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 
35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 
35.393, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.391, 35.391, 
35.391, 35.39, 35.39, 35.389, 35.388, 35.388, 35.388, 35.388, 
35.387, 35.38687, 35.38687, 35.38755, 35.38755, 35.38755, 35.38755, 
35.38786, 35.38932, 35.38932, 35.39029, 35.3903, 35.3903, 35.39162, 
35.39162, 35.39162, 35.38687, 35.38874, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 
35.387, 35.388, 35.388, 35.388, 35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 
35.391, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 
35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 
35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.392, 35.391, 35.391, 35.39, 
35.39, 35.388, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 35.388, 35.389, 
35.39, 35.39, 35.391, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.392, 
35.391, 35.391, 35.389, 35.389, 35.389, 35.387, 35.387, 35.387, 
35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.393, 35.393, 
35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.389, 35.389, 35.389, 35.387, 35.387, 
35.388, 35.389, 35.389, 35.389, 35.389, 35.39, 35.39, 35.39, 
35.391, 35.391, 35.392, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 
35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.393, 35.392, 35.392, 
35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.392, 35.391, 
35.391, 35.391, 35.391, 35.389, 35.389, 35.388, 35.388, 35.388, 
35.38688, 35.3894, 35.39325, 35.3931, 35.3933, 35.39275, 35.39175, 
35.38843, 35.38848, 35.38848, 35.38802, 35.3876, 35.38947, 35.39013, 
35.39013, 35.39286, 35.39108, 35.391, 35.38808, 35.38736, 35.38738, 
35.38561, 35.38785, 35.38782, 35.38874, 35.39086, 35.39091, 35.39088, 
35.39088, 35.39188, 35.39199, 35.39254, 35.39255, 35.39254, 35.39259, 
35.39317, 35.39315, 35.39314, 35.39316, 35.39317, 35.39328, 35.3933, 
35.39328, 35.39304, 35.39304, 35.39304, 35.39303, 35.39304, 35.39304, 
35.39223, 35.39225, 35.39168, 35.39167, 35.3909, 35.39088, 35.39088, 
35.39029, 35.3903, 35.38946, 35.38946, 35.38947, 35.38862, 35.3886, 
35.38864, 35.3886, 35.38861, 35.38804, 35.38805, 35.38687, 35.3869, 
35.38689, 35.38688, 35.38688, 35.38716, 35.38781, 35.38934, 35.38934, 
35.38935, 35.38936, 35.38938, 35.39081, 35.3908, 35.39082, 35.39077, 
35.39078, 35.39197, 35.39198, 35.39238, 35.39235, 35.39236, 35.39288, 
35.39288, 35.39288, 35.39289, 35.39288, 35.39288, 35.39329, 35.3933, 
35.39333, 35.3933, 35.39306, 35.39307, 35.3931, 35.39307, 35.39275, 
35.3917, 35.39168, 35.39168, 35.39074, 35.39075, 35.38874, 35.38872, 
35.38597, 35.3869, 35.38783, 35.38788, 35.38783, 35.38947, 35.39002, 
35.3912, 35.39124, 35.39119, 35.39121, 35.39119, 35.39241, 35.39258, 
35.39257, 35.39274, 35.39286, 35.39282, 35.39321, 35.39321, 35.39318, 
35.39328, 35.39305, 35.39308, 35.39243, 35.39242, 35.39216, 35.39042, 
35.39, 35.38908, 35.38849, 35.38849, 35.38844, 35.38683, 35.38761, 
35.38758, 35.38798, 35.3879, 35.38793, 35.38904, 35.38908, 35.38904, 
35.39165, 35.39226, 35.39225, 35.39224, 35.39226, 35.39045, 35.39047, 
35.38857, 35.3886, 35.3886, 35.38856, 35.38776, 35.388, 35.388, 
35.392, 35.38678, 35.38669, 35.388, 35.3881, 35.3881, 35.3881, 
35.3881, 35.38988, 35.38984, 35.38984, 35.39002, 35.39127, 35.39127, 
35.39127, 35.39158, 35.39335, 35.3931, 35.39278, 35.39286, 35.39204, 
35.39213, 35.39117, 35.3905, 35.38751, 35.38734, 35.38734, 35.38876, 
35.38877, 35.38876, 35.38877, 35.38877, 35.38997, 35.38998, 35.3912, 
35.3912, 35.3912, 35.3918, 35.39242, 35.39244, 35.39287, 35.39286, 
35.39285, 35.39317, 35.39314, 35.39316, 35.39316, 35.3932, 35.39307, 
35.39309, 35.39308, 35.39305, 35.39225, 35.39226, 35.39228, 35.39134, 
35.39095, 35.38687, 35.38689, 35.38724, 35.38727, 35.3874, 35.38874, 
35.38847, 35.3869, 35.38737, 35.38736, 35.38737, 35.38739, 35.38755, 
35.38806, 35.38806, 35.38813, 35.38813, 35.38813, 35.38813, 35.38867, 
35.39024, 35.39093, 35.39094, 35.39077, 35.39078, 35.39183, 35.39206, 
35.39342, 35.39344, 35.39359, 35.39269, 35.39244, 35.39235, 35.39225, 
35.39191, 35.39191, 35.39191, 35.3912, 35.38856, 35.38866, 35.38866, 
35.3868, 35.38685, 35.38684, 35.38685, 35.38682, 35.38687, 35.38686, 
35.38685, 35.38686, 35.38684, 35.3868, 35.38873, 35.3887, 35.38868, 
35.38874, 35.38869, 35.38952, 35.38944, 35.38948, 35.38952, 35.38948, 
35.39118, 35.39114, 35.3912, 35.39116, 35.39118, 35.39228, 35.39234, 
35.39232, 35.39295, 35.39298, 35.393, 35.39298, 35.39297, 35.39296, 
35.39298, 35.39326, 35.39324, 35.39287, 35.39286, 35.3924, 35.3924, 
35.3924, 35.39239, 35.39238, 35.39218, 35.39216, 35.3922, 35.39088, 
35.39087, 35.3909, 35.39089, 35.39088, 35.39087, 35.39092, 35.3885, 
35.3885, 35.3885, 35.38852, 35.3885, 35.3885, 35.3885)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-815L))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite easy with the base `smooth.spline` function or `principal_curve` in the princurve package. You may want to also explore the `loess`/`lowess` local polynomial regression functions. Here is an example with your data. Note that I reorder the columns to make the matrix coercion simpler. You can see that principal_curve shifts the curve a bit but finds the tails more effectively than smooth.spline. Exploring smoothing parameters may help you find an optimal solution.

```
x <- data.frame(long=x[,2],lat=x[,1])
  fit <- princurve::principal_curve(as.matrix(x))
  sfit <- smooth.spline(x[,1] ~ x[,2], spar=0.80)

plot(x[,1], x[,2], pch=19, main="Curve fit(s) of coordinates", 
     xlab="longitude", ylab="latitude", cex=0.50)
    lines(princurve::principal_curve(as.matrix(x)), lwd=1.25, col="red")
    lines(sfit$y, sfit$x, lwd=1.25, col="blue")
legend("bottomright", legend=c("spline","princurve"),
       lty=c(1,1), col=c("blue","red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I note its only 1 degree below the equator so the aspect ratio is pretty close to one - if this data was nearer the poles a reprojection to a cartesian system might be appropriate and change the result slightly.

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot2` has a geom for this called `geom_smooth`. The default curve is a loess line, which is similar to a moving average across the x-axis. This can be changed and fed formula as well.

```
library(tidyverse)



ggplot(data=transect,aes(x=long,y=lat)) + 
    geom_point( )+
    geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Comment: The problem here is that the data does not describe a functional relationship of the form `y=f(x)` and so most standard curve fitting or smoothing algorithms will blindly run down the middle of the presented data and not draw the obvious (to our eyes) curve.

Comment: Yes. There is no explicit formula as such - but it effective it is a parabola

Comment: Its a rotated parabola. If you want to fit a rotated parabola to your data then please edit your question to be explicit in that.

Comment: Given the imprecision of the OP's question, this answer is correct. Whoever down-voted should reconsider.

Comment: This does not look like "Fit a smooth spatial line through these points" given that it clearly isnt "through these points2. It looks like treating the latitude as a function of longitude and fitting a spline to that function. Happy to reconsider once the OP comments - but the other answers look more like I reckon is wanted.

Comment: @Spacedman, hence my mentioning the imprecision of the question. "Through" can mean a number of things, and this answer does, in fact, fit a curve "through" the points. The OP never updated his answer to specify that he wanted anything resembling, as you put it, to "draw the obvious (to our eyes) curve". Based on the OP's incomplete answer to his own question, your assumption appears to be correct, but I don't feel that elliot should have his score reduced for providing an accurate answer to the actual question that was asked.

Comment: @Tom if there is uncertainty in a question the correct thing to do is to ask for clarification in the comments and possibly vote the Q down as "Unclear what you're asking" until a response is received. It is clear now from the accepted answer that geom_smooth does not do what was wanted and this answer is now superfluous and should go. Note that downvoting loses *me* rep points as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found this that seems to work very well...

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271161/2d-curve-identification-and-smoothing?noredirect=1&lq=1

This was the outcome on the data:

[image]

Comment: This answer neither contains code nor addresses the question as asked. Please update your question to clarify your goal, and then provide your solution code in the answer.

Comment: Please avoid linked answers as sites tend to disappear with time.